# clearing a java string after loop

Tags: java, string, palindrome

I am new to Java and am creating a project for class that basically asks the user to input a string, and then tests the string and prints whether or not it is a palindrome (the same forwards as backwards... i.e. mom or dad or racecar)

I have gotten the code to work, however i have a loop setup to rerun the program or quit at the end.  My problem is that when you rerun the program and enter another String input then it's adding it to the original string.

How can I reset or delete the String input each time so that it starts fresh?

Thank you for any help!  Also please note, there may be better or faster ways to accomplish what I have done here but my knowledge of java is limited and I am just getting started, so I have used the knowledge that I have thus far learned.  Thanks!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Palindrome {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

      String input = ""; // Word entered by user
      String reverse = ""; //Reverse of String input
      String redoAnswer; // answer to rerun program

      int length; //length of word entered by user

      boolean test;
      boolean redo; // boolean to rerun program
      boolean exit; // boolean to validate exit/rerun


      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      do {
        redo = true;
        exit = true;

        System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
        input = scan.nextLine();

        length = input.length();

        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
          reverse = reverse + input.charAt(i);

        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(reverse)) {
          System.out.println("Yes, this string is a palindrome!");
        } else {

          System.out.println("Sorry, this string is NOT a palindrome!");
        }

        do {
          System.out.println("Please type r to restart or q to quit");
          redoAnswer = scan.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
          if (redoAnswer.equals("r")) {
            exit = false;
            redo = true;
            continue;
          } else if (redoAnswer.equals("q")) {
            exit = false;
            redo = false;
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            continue;
          } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, I didn't catch that.");
            continue;
          }
        } while (exit);
      } while (redo);
    } //end main
} //end class
```

Ok, figured it out thanks to your guys' help... also rewrote the code so that you can just keep entering new strings or type q to quit instead of the redo question at the end.  Hopefully this is cleaner!

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Palindrome_Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String input = ""; // Word entered by user
      String reverse = ""; //Reverse of String input

      int length; //length of word entered by user

      boolean redo = true; // boolean to rerun program

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      do {
        System.out.println("Please enter a string, or type Q to quit: ");
        input = scan.nextLine();
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
          System.out.println("Goodbye!");
          redo = false;
        } else {
          length = input.length();
          for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            reverse = reverse + input.charAt(i);

          if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(reverse)) {
            System.out.println("Yes, this string is a palindrome!");
          } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, this string is NOT a palindrome!");
          }
          reverse = "";
        }
      } while (redo);
    } //end main
} //end class
```

Comment: Your two do-whiles are a bit confusing. Right at the start of your first do-while-loop you define `exit = true`, Sounds as if your program was to exit the next time this variable is checked. But in reality, it is looped as long as `exit` stays `true` which doesn't make sense :-)! You could also think about a simple while loop in the style of `while(!redoAnswer.equals("q"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your while loop add `reverse = "";`

Comment: What should be cleared is `reverse`, not `input` because `input` will be overwritten by `input = scan.nextLine();`.

Comment: Hmmm, but @JordanHawkes wants to "reset or delete the String input". Why?

Comment: Because when he adds `reverse = reverse + input.charAt(i);` to the last solution that ran correct?

Comment: OMG, thank you!! You are right, i needed to set reverse = "";

I kept trying to reset the String input instead...

Thank you! Everything is working now!

Comment: No problem. If this is the correct answer please accept it and happy coding:)

Comment: yup it was just on a timer so i had to wait!  thank you again for your help!

Trying to edit my while loop to make it a little simpler to understand.  Will post if i figure something better out!

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice that I moved the following -

```
String input = ""; // Word entered by user
String reverse = ""; //Reverse of String input
```

Inside of the first loop. Although you could simply reset both variables at the end of the loop...

```
input = "";
reverse = "";
```

There is no need to (Although, they both work!). By dealing with the scope of the variable inside of the loop, it will essentially "refresh" each time the loop executes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class  Palindrome {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

   //  String input = ""; // Word entered by user
   //  String reverse = ""; //Reverse of String input
  String redoAnswer; // answer to rerun program

  int length; //length of word entered by user

  boolean test;
  boolean redo; // boolean to rerun program
  boolean exit; // boolean to validate exit/rerun


  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  do {
    redo = true;
    exit = true;

    String input = ""; // Word entered by user
    String reverse = ""; //Reverse of String input

    System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
    input = scan.nextLine();

    length = input.length();

    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      reverse = reverse + input.charAt(i);

    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(reverse)) {
      System.out.println("Yes, this string is a palindrome!");
    } else {

      System.out.println("Sorry, this string is NOT a palindrome!");
    }

    do {
      System.out.println("Please type r to restart or q to quit");
      redoAnswer = scan.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
      if (redoAnswer.equals("r")) {
        exit = false;
        redo = true;
        continue;
      } else if (redoAnswer.equals("q")) {
        exit = false;
        redo = false;
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        continue;
      } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, I didn't catch that.");
        continue;
      }
    } while (exit);

  } while (redo);
} //end main
} //end class
```